# Checking a field in one model while in a form for another model: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display certain fields in a form if a condition is satisfied on a different model.

Here is the example:

```
<%= form_for(@workout) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :workout_exercises do |s| %>
    <%= s.collection_select :exercise_id, Exercise.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => ""} %>              
    <%= s.label :sets %>:
    <%= s.number_field :set %>
    <% if @exercise.is_cardio == true %>
        <%= s.label :time %>(Minutes):
        <%= s.number_field :time %>     
    <% end %>
    <% end %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above gives a no method error on `is_cardio` is cardio is a boolean field in the exercises table

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :workouts, :through => :workout_exercises

end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :exercises, :through => :workout_exercises

class WorkoutExercise < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :workout
end
```

EDIT 2:

Specifically, here is the error I get:

```
undefined method `is_cardio' for #<Array:0x007fcd3bb93dd0>
```

Comment: How is @exercise defined?

Comment: an exercise 
has_many :workout_exercises
has_many :workouts, :through => :workout_exercises

Comment: @RichardBrown I just updated the question with the model associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you need to change

```
<% if @exercise.is_cardio == true %>
    <%= s.label :time %>(Minutes):
    <%= s.number_field :time %>     
<% end %>
```

to

```
<% if s.object.exercise.is_cardio == true %>
    <%= s.label :time %>(Minutes):
    <%= s.number_field :time %>     
<% end %>
```

Comment: That got me closer! I'm getting a syntax error I can't spot now: if s.@exercise.is_cardio == true It's pointing at the . after @exercise

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but you don't want `s.@exercise`. You want `s.exercise`. No @.

Comment: I tried @exercise because exercise threw a no method error on exercise: undefined method `exercise' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fcd3b5ba788>

Comment: Okay, what about `s.object.exercise.is_cardio`? (I updated my answer.)